# Instead of Form action and method

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="something" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

I find that there is no "action" and "method" as in

```
<form action="/application/controler/somepage.php" method="POST">
</form>
```

in which I would like to get the value entered in the text box after the button submit is pressed. How can I do the same (get the value submitted via POST or GET) as in the former ?

Also, in case I would like to get the value passed in the URL
`http://localhost/index.php/something?value=75&today=Wed`

that is `75` and `Wed`, for example.

Comment: better use `form_close()` instead of `</form>`. personal opinion to avoid IDE "code cleanup" problems.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
echo form_open('controller/somepage', array('method'=>'get'));
```

Comment: Indent your code by either adding 4 spaces before it or putting it between `` characters.

Answer (score 6):

The [CodeIgniter Form Helper Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) states that the first parameter you hand into the `form_open()` function is the URL you are posting to. URL Semantics are a large part of CodeIgniter, if you're posting to a location inside your application use:

> ```
> <?= form_open('index.php/controller/function/param1/param2');?>
> ```

CodeIgniter uses `method='post'` by default.

CodeIgniter does not natively support the form `method='get'` parameter because of the way it handles URLs. Instead of a URL:

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/something?value=75&today=Wed
```

The CodeIgniter way would be:

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/mycontroller/myfunction/75/Wed
```

You would then define a function in your controller as

```
function myfunction($value, $day)
{
//do whatever you want with the $value and the $day here.
}
```

Comment: Never tried using it, but CI now seems to support GET quite well.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
echo form_open('controller/somepage');
```

Have a look at the documentation:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want change method to `GET` you must add the attribute to `form_open()`

```
$attribute['method'] = 'get';
echo form_open(THE_ACTION_URL, $attribute);
```

or, you can make your own `helper` for faster method

```
function form_open_get($action, $attribute = NULL, $hidden = NULL)
{
    $attribute['method'] = 'get';
    return form_open($action,$attribute,$hidden);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the attribute before the form, for exemple:

```
$attributes = 'method="get"';
```